# Python Email Validation

Tags: python, email-validation

I have an old list of email addresses. I want to write a Python script to check which emails are still active and to which email can be sent. I tried using the validate_email package but it doesn't seem to work (e.g. when I input my own email address it says it's not deliverable). Any thoughts on how to do this in Python? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add all the dependencies for that package?

Comment: The only and best way to verify that an email account is still active is to try sending it an email.